# one to one отобразить в jsp

Tags: java-ee, hibernate, jsp, orm

подскажите как связать 2 таблицы правильно, и отобразить их в JSP.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Clients implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "clientsid")
    private Long clientsid;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "patronymic")
    private String patronymic;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="phonesid")
    private Phones phonesid;
```

не могу понять как правильно выгрузить на страницу.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phones")
public class Phones implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "phonesid")
    private Long phonesid;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "commetns")
    private String comments;
```

Comment: это клиенты и их телефоны? у каждого клиента только один телефон?

Comment: да верно @Mikhail Vaysman

Comment: просто у вас классы названы во множественном числе. это сбивает с толку. на страницу вы выводите одно клиента?

Comment: щас переимную спасибо завтыкал)))

да вывожу одного клиента с его номером телефона.

@Mikhail Vaysman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Быть может, что код у меня не самый лучший и адекватный))
**Предположим что Ваши Entity такие:**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity
@Table(name = "clients", catalog = "mybase")
public class Clients implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "clientsid")
    private Long clientsid;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "patronymic")
    private String patronymic;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="phonesid")
    private Phones phones;

    public Clients() {
    }

    public Long getClientsid() {
        return clientsid;
    }

    public void setClientsid(Long clientsid) {
        this.clientsid = clientsid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getPatronymic() {
        return patronymic;
    }

    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) {
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    public Phones getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(Phones phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }
}
```

**and**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "phones", catalog = "mybase")
public class Phones implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "phonesid")
    private Long phonesid;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "commetns")
    private String comments;

    public Phones() {
    }

    public Long getPhonesid() {
        return phonesid;
    }

    public void setPhonesid(Long phonesid) {
        this.phonesid = phonesid;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

---

**ФАЙЛ hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybase?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->

        <mapping class="Entity.Clients" />
        <mapping class="Entity.Phones" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

**pom.xml может быть таким**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>stackoverflowHIBERNATE</groupId>
  <artifactId>stackoverflowHIBERNATE</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>stackoverflowHIBERNATE Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>stackoverflowHIBERNATE</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

**Простенький DAO с одним методом - вытащить из базы все Clients. Данный класс будем использовать в сервлете** (подробнее по [ссылке](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm))

```
public class DaoClient {
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public List<Clients> getAllClients() {
        try{
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Clients> clientses = new ArrayList<Clients>();

        try{
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            clientses = (List<Clients>) session.createQuery("FROM Clients").list();
            transaction.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction!=null) transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return clientses;
    }
}
```

---

**Сервлета**

```
@WebServlet("/base")
public class SourceServlet extends HttpServlet {
    DaoClient daoClient = new DaoClient();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Clients> clientses = daoClient.getAllClients();
        request.setAttribute("Clients", clientses);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("base.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

---

**И сама JSP:** (если хотите реализовать "полный цикл" создания Clients из JSP и прочее прочее, то можно ознакмиться с данным  [роликом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7swABdqOS4))

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Base</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:if test="${!empty Clients}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${Clients}" var="clients">
        <tr>
            <td>${clients.name}</td>
            <td>${clients.surname}</td>
            <td>${clients.phones.number}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Структура проекта**
[image: Структура]

---

**Test.java нужен был лишь для insert'а в базу**

```
import Entity.Clients;
import Entity.Phones;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class Test {

    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Phones phones1 = new Phones();
        phones1.setNumber("911");
        phones1.setComments("Call me!");
        phones1.setType("MyType1");

        Phones phones2 = new Phones();
        phones2.setNumber("88005553535");
        phones2.setComments("don't forget");
        phones2.setType("ClassicType");



        Clients clients1 = new Clients();
        clients1.setName("Ivan");
        clients1.setSurname("Ivanov");
        clients1.setPatronymic("Pertovich");
        clients1.setPhones(phones1);

        Clients clients2 = new Clients();
        clients2.setName("Vladimir");
        clients2.setSurname("Kapustin");
        clients2.setPatronymic("Romanovich");
        clients2.setPhones(phones2);

        try{
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;


        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(clients1);
            session.save(clients2);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**web.xml дефолтный**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


</web-app>
```

---

**и еще о hibernate.cfg.xml** 
Предположим база в нем указана так

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybase</property>
```

Но таблицы там отсутствуют. Тогда снимаем комментарии со строки

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Это строка автоматически создаст таблицы при первом insert на основе аннотированных классов Clients и Phones. **Главное** после подобного автоматического создания таблиц - **обратно закомментировать строку** или удалить. Иначе каждый "рестарт" будет обнулять базу.

---

В итоге будет так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @CheshereK Спасибо за пример. Он не запускается(( буду смотреть дальше.

Comment: Сейчас дополню ответ, покажу структуру проекта. Вдруг где-то мы не поняли дргу друга)

Comment: @CheshieK В целом мне все понятно.

будем считать что ответ верный)))

проект не запускаеться((((

HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.testapp.servlet.SourceServlet

Comment: @Verlamov Не знаю структуру Вашего проекта. Могу лишь предположить так: удалить с сервлеты строку `@WebServlet("/base")`   и вручную прописать в `web.xml` сервлету  
   `<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sourceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.testapp.servlet.SourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sourceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/base</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`